# Clarification of derivation of Bohr radius according to Griffiths

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

I'm currently going through Griffiths QM (second ed.) and am on the section (page 150) where he derives the [Bohr radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius). This is the line he gives
$$
\kappa=\left(\frac{me^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}\right)\frac1n=\frac1{an}
$$

where $$\kappa=\frac{\sqrt{-2mE}}{\hbar}.$$

I understand how he obtained this equation
$$
\kappa=\left(\frac{me^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}\right)\frac1n
$$
however I dont understand how RHS of this equals $\frac{1}{an}$. I've searched for more in-depth derivations but they all use a method similar to [this](https://alpha.chem.umb.edu/chemistry/ch115/carter/files/103more/BohrEquations.pdf) (which I understand) but don't follow the method of Griffiths.

All I need is the explanation of how $\kappa=\frac{1}{an}$ (I *think* it requires to show $\kappa=\frac{1}{r_n n}$ then let $n=1$ (for the ground state) and hence get the Bohr radius)

Comment: Isn't $\left(\frac{me^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}\right)\frac1n=\frac1{an}$ just the definition of $a$?

Comment: I.e. $a:=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}{me^2}$?

Comment: @Filippo I thought about that, that it may just be a definition, but I wasn't too comfortable with using that to explain away my doubts because it's not intuitive that K is proportional to inverse of Bohr Radius. Hence I seek an explanation as to why

Answer (score 2):

As @Filippo said in the comment, It's the definition of Bohr radius. Yet another way to think of is to say that "Bohr radius provides the natural length scale for Hydrogen atom problem."

To see this, You can [non-dimensionalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization) the equation
$$\left\{ \frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\left[E+\frac{e^2}{r}-\frac{l(l+1)\hbar^2}{2mr^2}\right]\right\}\mathcal{U}_{El}=0$$
Putting $r=r_c\tau$, We have
$$\left\{ \frac{d^2}{d\tau^2}+\frac{2mr_c^2}{\hbar^2}\left[E+\frac{e^2}{r_c\tau}-\frac{l(l+1)\hbar^2}{2mr_c^2\tau^2}\right]\right\}\mathcal{U}_{El}=0$$
Equating the second term in big bracket to 1,  We have
$$\frac{2m r_ce^2}{\hbar^2}=1\rightarrow r_c=\frac{\hbar^2}{2me^2}=\frac{a}{2}$$
as desired!

Comment: I think I somewhat get the non-dimensionalization part, but how can a non-arbitrary value like the Bohr radius just be "defined"? To me such an action is equal to saying "let the Bohr radius be 1cm"

Comment: @watertruck Bohr radius is a natural unit made of the constants in the problem. It is arbitrary up to constant. You can equally define it to be $a=\text{constant}\times r_c$. The constant is chosen to be half just because in a state with principal quantum number $n$, The maximal probability for a particle to be found is equal to $n^2a$.

Comment: I think i see what you mean. I think I understand it a bit more now. Thanks!